Send the current slide as a .pptx attachment in email
I am using office.js in a React application to perform different PowerPoint specific operations. As per one of the latest requirements, it is needed that the currently selected slide be sent as an attachment (.pptx file) in an email. I am using Microsoft graph API endpoint "sendMail" to send the email and there is an option to specify attachment as a base64 string (contentBytes parameter)
As per my findings there is an office js method called exportAsBase64 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.slide?view=powerpoint-js-preview#powerpoint-powerpoint-slide-exportasbase64-member(1)) that might do the job. However, it is available only in preview API. Can anyone help with this requirement by using the release version of office.js? Maybe somehow save the active slide as a .pptx in the user's machine and then send it as an attachment as a next step? Or maybe somehow extract the base64 string of the active slide and then use it.
